# BuildConfig is defines multiple times in a KMM project

Tags: android, build, android-r8, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile, kmm

I am wokring on a Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile (KMM) project and was trying to generate a signed release app bundle for the Android Application and came across this error

> Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.internal.b: Type `packageName`.BuildConfig is defined multiple times

One `BuildConfig` is spotted in the Android `app` module, another is in the `shared` module, with the same package name.

This is from my app module Gradle

```
buildTypes {
    getByName("release") {
        isMinifyEnabled = false
    }
}
```

I haven't faced this issue for Building Debug Apk or App Bundle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd try out the following:

1. Ensure that your `shared` and `app` modules have different package names
2. Try doing a clean-build/rebuild

Comment: Changing package name worked, thank you

Comment: Indeed, for some reason both Manifest files have the same package id...

Answer (score 2):

Check namespace field which is located gradle of each module. If they are same, could cause build error.

```
android {
       namespace "com.CompanyName.ProjectName.core.util"
       compileSdk ProjectConfig.compileSdk
       ......
```